# QueryExecute equivalent to new Query getPrefix()

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I have some existing code

```
local.query = new Query();
local.query = setDataSource(application.DSN);
local.setSQL("
  SELECT ... 
  ");

local.result = local.query.execute(); // I am OK up to this point

local.prefix = local.result.getPrefix();
```

I understand that this gets the meta information for the query.

How do I convert this to

```
local.prefix = QueryExecute("
 SELECT ... 
 ",
 [],
 {datasource : application.DSN}
 );
```

Now what? Where do I do `getPrefix()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resultset is returned from `queryExecute()`

```
local.result = QueryExecute("
 SELECT ... ", [],
 {datasource : application.DSN}
 ); 

local.prefix = result.prefix
```